# playing vimeo in IE8 with popcorn.js

Tags: internet-explorer-8, vimeo, popcornjs

I can't get popcorn.js to play ball with IE8. I'm using the popcorn-ie8 wrapper, the media proto and vimeo plugin ONLY.

My code is as simple as this:

```
var video = Popcorn.HTMLVimeoVideoElement('#video');
video.src = 'http://vimeo.com/18359846';
var example = Popcorn(video);
example.play()
```

IE8 throws an error:

'MediaError is undefined', popcorn._MediaElementProto.js (58).

If I use a full package distro of popcorn.js and put the IE8 shim at the top, my IE leaks memory rapidly and crashes. I also had to disable memory protection in IE8 in order to capture the error, since otherwise the whole browser crashes.

So I've cut it down to just popcorn+ie8shim, the mediaelement core and the vimeo plugin.

I have set up a jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/EtepN/

You have to use this url to see the result in IE8, since jsFiddle doesn't work in IE8 : http://jsfiddle.net/EtepN/embedded/result/

-- **edit** --

getting closer; I've created a closure for MediaError so that IE8 doesn't throw an error on it being undefined - just define it as another object and set *that* to the MediaError object.

```
(function(w) {
var _MediaError = w.MediaError;
if(!_MediaError) {
w.MediaError = _MediaError = (function() {
    function MediaError(code, msg) {
      this.code = code || null;
      this.message = msg || "";
    }
    MediaError.MEDIA_ERR_NONE_ACTIVE    = 0;
    MediaError.MEDIA_ERR_ABORTED        = 1;
    MediaError.MEDIA_ERR_NETWORK        = 2;
    MediaError.MEDIA_ERR_DECODE         = 3;
    MediaError.MEDIA_ERR_NONE_SUPPORTED = 4;

    return MediaError;
  }());
}
}(window));
```

Still not getting it to work in IE8 but that's one error down at least ....

Comment: i'm going to take a look, but i'm curious, how did you get the ie8 fiddle url? or is that just the result document, that gets embedded into fiddles?

Comment: the share button has the url, a iframe embed, ...

Comment: here's your bug: https://webmademovies.lighthouseapp.com/projects/65733/tickets/2885-crash-uncaught-referenceerror-mediaerror-is-not-defined-httpspopcornwebmakerorgexternalpopcorn-jspopcornjs5240   ticket is marked won't fix. i fiddled with adding window as described in the ticket, but it just led to more errors in the popcorn.js repo i downloaded. sorry. hope you can figure something out from that.

Comment: @albert: won't fix? I've been tinkering myself. Got MediaError to stop showing undefined, at least (see edit)... still tinkering

Comment: won't fix....i'm assuming that means they're not going to fix it. kewl, i'll check it out in a few.